# Use limit definition to find derivative of $x+\sqrt x$

Tags: limits, derivatives

The function is $f(x) = x + \sqrt x$.
How would you use the limit definition of the derivative to find the derivative of that equation?

Comment: Have you tried writing out the definition of the derivative?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You may want to look at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how to use MathJax for formulas here. Also you should show some of your own work (write out the definition and try to play with it)

Answer (score 3):

We have

> $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Let $$f(x) = x + \sqrt x$$

$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h + \sqrt {x+h})-(x + \sqrt x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h + \sqrt {x+h} - \sqrt x}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}1+\frac{ \sqrt {x+h} - \sqrt x}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}1+\frac{ \sqrt {x+h} - \sqrt x}{h}\frac{\sqrt {x+h} + \sqrt x}{\sqrt {x+h} + \sqrt x}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}1+\frac{x+h - x}{h( \sqrt {x+h} + \sqrt x)}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}1+\frac{h}{h( \sqrt {x+h}+ \sqrt x)}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}1+\frac{1}{ \sqrt {x+h} + \sqrt x}\\
&=1+\frac{1}{ \sqrt {x} + \sqrt x}\\
f'(x)&=1+\frac{1}{ 2\sqrt {x} }\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
You know that the result must be $f'(x) = 1 + \frac1{2\sqrt x}$ so you know where you are headed. Now just play with the definition
$$f'(x) := \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(x+h+\sqrt{x+h}) - (x + \sqrt x)}h = \ldots$$